# Procedures in apoc.mongodb deprecated

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to connect Mongodb with Neo4j via APOC. I get a warning of deprecation:

```
This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
The query used a deprecated procedure. ('apoc.mongodb.get' is no longer supported)
EXPLAIN CALL apoc.mongodb.get('mongodb://localhost:27017','dataset','Product',{PieceId:1234}) yield value
```

The same happens with other procedures in apoc.mongodb. I haven't found any official communication that apoc.mongodb will be deprecated, so I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong. Any idea?

Versions:

- Neo4j 4.1.2
- Neo4j Desktop 1.3.8
- Plugins: apoc-4.1.0.1-all.jar,
  apoc-mongodb-dependencies-4.1.0.1.jar
- MongoDB 4.4.0 Community

Thanks,

Francesco